# How to select the latest records from time series data for each patient id in python and we have to merge the hourly data into days

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

dataset image link attached below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO17u.png)

```
**ID         date         ag  o   admision    discharge   a   b    c   d   e**
1   2020-01-31 01:09:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-01-31 01:25:00 73  1   ########    ########    0       136     
    2020-01-31 01:44:00 73  1   ########    ########    0           103.1   
    2020-01-31 01:45:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               13.9
    2020-01-31 01:56:00 73  1   ########    ########    0   19.9            
    2020-01-31 01:59:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-01-31 02:09:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-01-31 06:44:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-02-04 19:42:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-02-06 09:14:00 73  1   ########    ########    0       140     
    2020-02-06 10:06:00 73  1   ########    ########    0           101.4   
    2020-02-10 12:42:00 73  1   ########    ########    0       130     
    2020-02-10 14:41:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               14.1
    2020-02-10 14:47:00 73  1   ########    ########    0           98.5    
    2020-02-15 09:58:00 73  1   ########    ########    0       129     
    2020-02-15 10:41:00 73  1   ########    ########    0           98.1    
    2020-02-15 10:50:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-02-16 08:53:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-02-16 08:55:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-02-16 09:23:00 73  1   ########    ########    0       131     
    2020-02-16 10:59:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               
    2020-02-16 11:32:00 73  1   ########    ########    0           100 
    2020-02-16 13:33:00 73  1   ########    ########    0               12.4
    2020-02-17 08:31:00 73  1   ########    ########    0
```

i tried this

```
tra=tra.resample('D').sum()
```

but it summed all the rows from the dataset of each date but i need to sum it for each patient as per ID.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to groupby Patient Id and do the operation.

```
tra=tra.groupby('PATIENT_ID').apply(lambda x: x.resample('D').sum())
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: getting this error 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'tz'